# Visual Studio 2010 - Constructor using Boolean.Parse throwing Format Exception at runtime-

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, constructor, boolean

Trying to be as concise as possible here.

I have a class file with 5 Boolean Properties, one of which looks like this:

```
Property StereoCheckBox() As Boolean
    Get
        Return stereoCheckBoxBoolean
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        If value = True Then
            stereoCheckBoxBoolean = value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Now in my Form file, I have 2 Text Boxes, 3 Check Boxes and 2 Radio Buttons that I need to be used for calculations in my class file.  I don't have any problem with the text boxes using Double.Parse, but for the life of me I cannot figure out the syntax for how the check boxes and radio buttons would go.

I know I need to send over a True or False based on if the box or button is clicked, but cannot figure out how to code it in the constructor.

For instance this is one of the things I tried that is incorrect:

```
Purchases = New Purchase(Double.Parse(TextBox1.Text), Double.Parse(TextBox2.Text), _ 
Boolean.Parse(CheckBox1.Checked), Boolean.Parse(Checkbox2.Checked), _ 
Boolean.Parse(CheckBox3.Checked), Boolean.Parse(RadioButton1.Checked), _ 
Boolean.Parse(RadioButton2.Checked))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I scoured the internet for something similar to my problem before asking, but came up empty.

Comment: So, your `SteroCheckBox setter` should only change the value of `stereoCheckBoxBoolean` to `true`?  It should never be set to `false`?  Do you set it to false via other methods of the class?

Comment: I recommend that you use additional variables to do the `Double.Parse`s on separate lines. It will make it much easier to track down problems.

Comment: No it shouldn't change it to true.  What I need is for a True or a False (depending on if the button/box is clicked) to be sent over to my class file, and if the button is clicked (true) it changes the variable to true which then goes through my Calculate Method which has if/elseif statements based on if the button boolean variable is true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a boolean datatype you don't need to parse it. I would suggest you to remove `Boolean.Parse` function.

So change your code from

```
Boolean.Parse(CheckBox1.Checked)
```

To

```
CheckBox1.Checked
```

Comment: I asked how to go about sending these true or false over to the class file yesterday and someone suggested Boolean.Parse. Removing the Boolean.Parse from each argument and leaving the .Checked still leaves me with a Format Exception. It goes away with a Try/Catch Block, but it always activates my catch.

Comment: the exception does not go away if you are catching it

Comment: I had to tinker with some code, but the .Checked was all I needed.  I tried this yesterday, but kept activating my catch, now after some rest I saw why that was happening.  Thanks for your help.